# Dispaly specific page portion if checkbox value is true in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
**Hide This Div If Checkbox is true **
```

setOpenDisclaimer(false)
    }}>
     {
    setOpenDisclaimer(false)
    }} />
    
    {`Stocks (equities), options, futures, forex, and crypto involve a high degree of risk and are not suitable for all investors as the special risks inherent to trading may expose investors to potentially significant losses.`}
                
                
                                        `/>
                }
                    label="Do Not Show This Message Again"
                />
            </div>

            <DialogActions style={{ justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
                <Link to="/terms"
                    style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}
                    className={classes.link}>
                    <strong>Learn More</strong>
                </Link>
                <Button
                    type="submit"
                    style={{ backgroundColor: '#3b3591', color: '#FFFFFF', textTransform: "none", }}
                    text={"I Agree"}
                    onClick={() => {
                        setOpenDisclaimer(false)
                    }}>
                    I Agree
                    </Button>
            </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>`

**This one is the whole dialogue box that I want to hide if Checkbox value is set to True**

Comment: Please format your code according to the markdown standard

Answer (score 0):

use conditionals {!checkbox?{your_dialog_box_div_here}:null}